# Please suggest xpath to print "Vor 16 Stunden"

Tags: selenium, webdriver

```
<tr id="$PCaseContentsPage$ppxResults$l1" class=" cellCont" pl_index="1">
  <td class="hiddenCell " style="height:24px;">
  <td>
  <td>
  <div class="oflowDivM">
    <nobr>
    <div title="16 Stunden, 20 Minuten, 10 seconds Vor." style="text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden;text-align:left;width:100%;white-space:nowrap;color: #DD0000; font-weight:bold;">
      Vor 16 Stunden
    </div>
```

I want to print `"Vor 16 Stunden"` using Webdriver.  The following is not working

```
driver.findelement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='$PCaseContentsPage$ppxResults$l1']/td[3]/div/nobr/div")).getText();
```

Comment: Please add the HTML you are using.

Comment: .//*[@id='$PCaseContentsPage$ppxResults$l1']/td[3]/div/nobr/div

Comment: <tr id="$PCaseContentsPage$ppxResults$l1" class=" cellCont" pl_index="1">
<td class="hiddenCell " style="height:24px;">
<td>
<td>
<div class="oflowDivM">
<nobr>
<div title="16 Stunden, 20 Minuten, 10 seconds Vor." style="text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden;text-align:left;width:100%;white-space:nowrap;color: #DD0000; font-weight:bold;">Vor 16 Stunden</div>

Comment: please add this HTML snippet to your question. Click the "edit" link under the question itself and update it.

Comment: Also I want to print "16 Stunden, 20 Minuten, 10 seconds Vor."

Answer (score 2):

you can for example go for:

```
string xpath = "//tr[@id='$PCaseContentsPage$ppxResults$l1']//div[contains(@title, '16 Stunden')]"
string text = driver.findelement(By.xpath(xpath)).getText();
```

Comment: great! glad to be of help!